# service state request callback function, error: Invalid number of arguments

Tags: ros, executive-smach, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I created a service with the following definition and i called it navigation.srv:

```
float64 srvtype
float64 wayPointX
float64 wayPointY
float64 wayPointZ
float64 LDFlag
---
std_msgs/String navResponse
```

Then I used the service state machine provided from smach and following the tutorials:

```
import roslib;  
import rospy
import actionlib 
import smach
import smach_ros
import time
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import RegionOfInterest
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped 
from kuri_msgs.srv import navigation

from kuri_msgs.msg import Object
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from smach_ros import ServiceState

 FixPoseX = 0   
 FixPoseY = 0 
 FixPoseZ = 10  


class Ch1():
 rospy.init_node('ch1_state_machine')
 sm = smach.StateMachine(outcomes=['Done'])

 with sm:

    def exploration_request_cb (userdata,request):
        exploration_request = navigation().Request  
        exploration_request.srvtype=1
        exploration_request.wayPointX = FixPoseX
        exploration_request.wayPointY = FixPoseY
        exploration_request.wayPointZ = FixPoseZ
        exploration_request.LDFlag = 0
        return exploration_request


    
        smach.StateMachine.add('EXPLORATION',
                ServiceState('controller_service',
                navigation,
                request  = exploration_request_cb),
                       transitions={'succeeded':'MARKER_DETECTION' , 'aborted':'Done', 'preempted':'EXPLORATION'})

    ### MORE STATES HERE

 sis = smach_ros.IntrospectionServer('server_name', sm, '/SM_ROOT')
     sis.start()

     # Execute SMACH plan
     outcome = sm.execute()
     rospy.spin()
     sis.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   Ch1()
```

The Service the I am using to be called ( I am also having a problem in sending back a response is as follow)

when I run the state machine it says that it is waiting for the service then I run the service the output is the following:

```
 import roslib
 import rospy
 from kuri_msgs.msg import *
 from kuri_msgs.srv import navigation
 from kuri_msgs.srv import navigationResponse
 from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped 
 from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry 

 class ControllerService:
         def __init__(self):
               print 'Starting Service 1'
               self.s = rospy.Service('controller_service', navigation , self.pos_vel_controller)   

        def pos_vel_controller(self , req):
            self.landFlagDone = req.LDFlag 
                if req.srvtype == 1 :
                         x = req.wayPointX
             y  = req.wayPointY
                 z = req.wayPointZ
             if self.landFlagDone >0:
#######################3 How to return a response here ???????????????????
                 return 'succeeded'
             else: 
                    return 'aborted'
        
                  
def main(args):
  rospy.init_node('Controller_Service')
  Controller = ControllerService()
  try:
     rospy.spin()
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Shutting down"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

In the service terminal
Killed

In the state machine terminal

```
 TypeError: Invalid number of arguments, args should be ['srvtype', 'wayPointX', 'wayPointY', 'wayPointZ', 'LDFlag'] args are(<function exploration_request_cb at 0x7f0f3fae6140>,)
```

What is the mistake in this code and how can I fix it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254099/service-state-request-callback-function,-error:-invalid-number-of-arguments/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> exploration_request = navigation().Request
> ```

that is not the correct type for a Python ROS Service request.

It should probably be `navigationRequest`.

PS: ROS naming conventions are actually to CamelCase service definitions, so `Navigation` would be better (although it's still way too generically named).

---

Edit: you've probably seen it, but just to make sure: [Writing a Simple Service and Client (Python)]([http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(python\)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(python%5C))). Section 1.1 shows how to instantiate a `Response`, but the principle is the same for `Request`s.

---

Edit2:

> ```
> from kuri_msgs.srv import navigation
> ```

Just add the `Request` type to this line, something like:

```
from kuri_msgs.srv import navigation, navigationRequest
```

like you do in the `Controller_Service` file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2017-02-08**:
@avdhoorn Thanks for answering. I tried using navigationRequest but I got the following error NameError: global name 'navigationRequest' is not defined

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2017-02-08**:
@avdhoorn I am defining a string as you can see in the srv file for the response( i can change it to be string navResponse) variable .. but how can I fill it with a string data and return it as a response. I tried too much but without any luck

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-08**:\

> NameError: global name 'navigationRequest' is not defined

please include all relevant parts of your program in your OP. Especially your `import ..` statements.

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2017-02-08**:
@gvdhoorn I edited the question and I added the service the I am using

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2017-02-09**:
@gvdhoorn I tried adding this import library but it is not working It give me this error

```
return navigationResponse.navResponse("succeeded")\n', "TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object is not callable\n"]
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-09**:
I don't understand what you copy-pasted. Please update your question with the complete error output.

Also: `navigationResponse.navResponse` does not make sense to me.

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2017-02-12**:
@gvdhoorn what is the type of the response that I should provide in case of using the service state machine ?? is it string or something else ? because when using service state machine there are only three options of response which are the succeeded, aborted and pre-empted

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2017-02-12**:
@gcdhoorn for your last question I changed the way of returning the response to be like this

```
return navigationResponse.navResponse("succeeded")
```

which is the name if the srv response msg followed by the variable for the response and then filling it with the response msg. Then I got that error